# Drop down Jquery/CSS menu not responding on iPad/iPhone

Tags: jquery, ipad, menu, navigation, device

I've been designing and coding up my website and the simple drop down menu doesn't work when viewing the site on an iPad or iPhone.

I've looked around and tried to implement some of the solutions that are online, ie jquery snippets that recognise when the user is using a particular kind of device, but to no avail. I'm not sure if its because these methods are deprecated or because I'm doing it wrong (probably the latter)

The website in question is http://www.sotomayormac.com

the top menu item: "Our thinking" drops down to a submenu via a href=# link. This gets highlighted ( a:hover) when its tapped on an iPad/iPhone, but no submenu appears. I'm pretty sure this is a key part of the problem.

html code for the menu is as follows:

```
 <!-- Start of MENU -->
 <ul id="ddmenu">
<li><a id="topLink" href="#">Our thinking</a>
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Showcase</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About us</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

the corresponding CSS:

```
#ddmenu {
background: #fff no no-repeat;
margin-left:50px;
padding: 0;
height:43px;
width:200px;
}

#ddmenu li {
float: left;
list-style: none;
margin-left:0px;
}

#ddmenu li a {
background:#fff;
display: block;
padding: 0px 0px;
text-decoration: none;
width: 70px;
color:#000;
white-space: nowrap;
text-align:left;
}

#ddmenu li a:hover {
background: #fff;
color:#666;
}

#ddmenu li ul {
margin: 10px 0 0 0px;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
visibility: hidden;
width:600px;
}

#ddmenu li ul li {
display:inline;
}

#ddmenu li ul li a {
width: auto;
background: #fff  right no-repeat;
display: inline;
color: #000;
padding-right:10px;
}

#ddmenu li ul li a:hover {
background: #fff no-repeat;
color:#666;
}
```

and jquery:

```
// <![CDATA[
var timeout    = 500;
var closetimer = 500;
var ddmenuitem = 0;

function ddmenu_open(){
    ddmenu_canceltimer();
       ddmenu_close();
       ddmenuitem = $(this).find('ul').css('visibility', 'visible');
}

function ddmenu_close(){
    if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.css('visibility', 'hidden');
}

function ddmenu_timer(){
    closetimer = window.setTimeout(ddmenu_close, timeout);
}

function ddmenu_canceltimer(){
    if(closetimer){
        window.clearTimeout(closetimer);
            closetimer = null;
}}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#ddmenu > li').bind('mouseover', ddmenu_open)
    $('#ddmenu > li').bind('mouseout',  ddmenu_timer)
});

document.onclick = ddmenu_close;
// ]]>
```

I think thats about it. I'm a noob on this kind of stuff so any help would be much appreciated. It's probably staring me right in the face but I cant figure it out!

Cheers

ALL the jscript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});
$("#slideshow").css("overflow", "hidden");

$("ul#slides").cycle({
fx: 'fade',
speed: 2000,
timeout: 8000,
pause: true,
prev: '#prev',
next: '#next',
after:     onAfter
});

function onAfter(curr,next,opts) {
var caption =(opts.currSlide + 1) + ' / ' + opts.slideCount;
$('#caption').html(caption);
}

$(".button").hover(function() {
    $(this).attr("src","socialnetworks_hover_03.gif");
        }, function() {
    $(this).attr("src","socialnetworks_05.gif");
});

// <![CDATA[
var timeout    = 500;
var closetimer = 500;
var ddmenuitem = 0;

function ddmenu_open(){
    ddmenu_canceltimer();
       ddmenu_close();
       ddmenuitem = $(this).find('ul').css('visibility', 'visible');
}

function ddmenu_close(){
    if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.css('visibility', 'hidden');
}

function ddmenu_timer(){
    closetimer = window.setTimeout(ddmenu_close, timeout);
}

function ddmenu_canceltimer(){
    if(closetimer){
        window.clearTimeout(closetimer);
            closetimer = null;
}}

var toggle_clicked = false;
function ddmenu_toggle(){
if(toggle_clicked) {
    toggle_clicked = false;
    ddmenu_timer();
} else {
    toggle_clicked = true;
    ddmenu_open();
}
}

$(document).ready(function(){
if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) ||              (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))) { 
    $('#ddmenu > li').bind('click', ddmenu_toggle);
} else {
    $('#ddmenu > li').bind('mouseover', ddmenu_open);
    $('#ddmenu > li').bind('mouseout',  ddmenu_timer);  
}
});

document.onclick = ddmenu_close;
// ]]>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iPad/iPhone doesn't support `mouseover`, `mouseout` events.

You need to use `click` event or `touchstart`, `touchend` for mobile browsers with touchscreen support.

For example for iPad/iPhone device write `$('#ddmenu > li').bind('click', ddmenu_open)` instead of `$('#ddmenu > li').bind('mouseover', ddmenu_open)`

**UPDATE**:

Replace your code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#ddmenu > li').bind('mouseover', ddmenu_open)
    $('#ddmenu > li').bind('mouseout',  ddmenu_timer)
});
```

to this:

```
var toggle_clicked = false;
function ddmenu_toggle(){
    if(toggle_clicked) {
        toggle_clicked = false;
        ddmenu_timer();
    } else {
        toggle_clicked = true;
        ddmenu_open();
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))) { 
        $('#ddmenu > li').bind('click', ddmenu_toggle);
    } else {
        $('#ddmenu > li').bind('mouseover', ddmenu_open);
        $('#ddmenu > li').bind('mouseout',  ddmenu_timer);  
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your advice, so would something along these lines be what I'm looking for?
`if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))) { $(document).ready(function(){ $('#ddmenu > li').bind('click', ddmenu_open) $('#ddmenu > li').bind('mouseout', ddmenu_timer) }); }`

Comment: hmm its still not working...I'll include the complete script file maybe I'm not doing something right...for example theres two document.ready things so that might cause a problem

Comment: yeah< i just implemented it as you can see from my edited post, but still doesnt work...which made me think it might have something to do with previous code that I hadnt included. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I was trying to figure this out and something struck me...if we're trying to tell javascript that the hover should be made into a click when viewing on an ipad/iphone, would it not be logical to call out the a:hover of the #ddmenu?
 and then should the `ddmenuitem = $(this).find('ul').css('visibility', 'visible');` not be changed to reflect that?, ie the ('ul') to something..?

Comment: iPhone/iPad didn't support `:hover` pseudo-selector either.

Comment: ok but its not working for some reason so there has to be something wrong with the code...is it normal that

`$(document).ready(function(){
    if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))) { 
        $('#ddmenu > li').bind('click', ddmenu_toggle);
    } else {
        $('#ddmenu > li').bind('mouseover', ddmenu_open);
        $('#ddmenu > li').bind('mouseout',  ddmenu_timer);`
is targeting #ddmenu > li when there is
`ddmenuitem = $(this).find('ul').css('visibility', 'visible');
}` 

that targets 'ul'?

Comment: Ok, I've make simple demo http://jsfiddle.net/xqfQq/. Please note that `document.onclick = ddmenu_close;` line is commented!

Comment: Thanks u, and sorry for the endless comments!

Answer (score 0):

You're using `mouseover` and `mouseout`, which are not supported on touch screens.

See the documentation about Apple's [JavaScript touch events](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/safariwebcontent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html).

You can use it like that:

```
document.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
    // Do sth.
}, false);
```